# How to upload extension in magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2

How to install custom extension in Magento2? I have zip file of an extension and i want to upload to Magento2 in localhost. How can i do this ?

Comment: You should just be able to unzip it into the local folder?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

It very simple to install extension in Magento 2.

1. First check there is code folder under app. If not then create it.
2. Unzip your extension then go to app/code folder of extension. If exist otherwise copy your extension 
   upload under app/code folder
3. Now run the following commands
   php bin/magento module:enable  // you can get this name from your config file under etc folder.
   php bin/magento setup:upgrade

   After that clear pub/static files except .htaccess and var/ files except .htaccess and run deploy command

   php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

   That's All